# php mail function

Tags: php, smtp

I am using PHP to send an email with headers like this:

```
From: danny@mydomain.com
To: dannyfriend@gmail.com
```

When I check the headers in dannyfriend@gmail.com's (the recipient) email client, I see this header:

```
Received: from admin by gator1815.hostgator.com with local (Exim 4.69)
    (envelope-from <danny@mydomain.com>)
```

But sometimes the mail goes to dannyfriend's spam folder, because the email is sent via hostgator.com not via mydomain.com as in the sender's email address.

What is really happening here? Why isn't it like this:

```
 Received: from admin by somename.mydomain.com with local (Exim 4.69)
        (envelope-from <danny@mydomain.com>)
```

I have seen [an article](http://www.transio.com/content/how-pass-spam-filters-php-mail) describing this problem. Can somebody shine some light on what is happening with the SMTP server?

**Summary:**
Why is the SMTP server not using the message from `FROM:` header as the envelope-from?

Comment: So why can't you just use a `Reply-To` header?

Comment: i understand that you can work around the spam problem with the `Reply-To` header, but i need the `From:` header to make the email looks better on the recipient's email client,**somename@gator1815.hostgator.com** is really ugly.

Answer (score 0):

You are actually using anonymous smtp relay. Your ISP provider probably the hostgator in that case is sending email on behalf of the email address that you are using. You may need to qualify your server to be a valid SMTP server that can receive and send emails. If the header does not match the actual from domain, the mail client or the receiving end suspects that it is coming from a fraudulent address and marks it as spam.

Comment: you are talking about the envelope-from right? is it hard to get a server like that? can i do that easily say on AWS EC2 with my own server software?

Comment: it is more of configuring your MX records, I think